# How to encrypt decrypt blob in azure blob using key vault secret

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault

How to encrypt/decrypt blob in azure blob storage. I tried the following but when i download the blob using a different secret, instead of getting any error , i am able to download without any issue. Am i missing
something? Here is my code:

```
string secretKey = "https://testkeyvault.vault.azure.net:433/secrets/SampleSecret1";

KeyVaultKeyResolver cloudResolver = new KeyVaultKeyResolver(AzureHelper.GetAccessToken);

IKey cloudKey1 = cloudResolver.ResolveKeyAsync(secretKey, CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
BlobEncryptionPolicy encryptionPolicy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(cloudKey1, cloudResolver);
client.DefaultRequestOptions.EncryptionPolicy = encryptionPolicy;
client.DefaultRequestOptions.RequireEncryption = true;

CloudBlockBlob blob1 = container.GetBlockBlobReference("blockblob2"); // this blob was uploaded using a different secretKey
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\Test\test2.txt", FileMode.Create))
{
    blob1.DownloadToStream(file);
}
```

AzureHelper.GetAccessToken:

```
internal static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
{
    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ClientId"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ClientKey"));

    AuthenticationContext ctx = new AuthenticationContext(new Uri(authority).AbsoluteUri, false);
    AuthenticationResult result = await ctx.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential);

    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

Comment: Your resolver is relevant here, so you'll need to post what that does.

Comment: What happens when you open this text file? Can you read the contents of that file?

Comment: When i download the encrypted file, it is in encrypted format. That is working fine.

Comment: You have another similar question going. I'm unclear which represents your current status: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226793/azure-blob-metadata-property-encryptiondata-is-not-set-after-setting-encryption/

Comment: i noticed your port for the vault is 433, is this intended?